# Why are my DIVS not reacting to any widths i give them?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I've been touching the surface on Flex lately to try and get some funky layouts.

However i have come across an issue where my divs are just not recognising widths?

***I am trying to set the first div of each row to 5% so they all line up along the left.***

I have tried giving them 5% and 5vw just to see if anything would change but no luck.

***I will organise into classes but just wanted to get it working first.***

The parent div has a widthof 100% too so it has a reference.

***My HTML***

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title></title>
  <link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="all">
  <style type="text/css">
    /* Grid styles */
    
    .column {
      /*flex-basis: 100%;*/
    }
    
    @media screen and (min-width: 800px) {
      .row {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: row;
        flex-wrap: nowrap;
      }
      .column {
        flex: 1;
      }
      ._25 {
        flex: 2.5;
      }
      ._5 {
        flex: 5;
      }
    }
    /**
    {
      border: 1px dashed red;
    }*/
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <!-- Personal user row -->
  <div class="row" style="height: 30vh; border-bottom: 1px solid black; width: 100%;">
    <div class="column" style="background-color: pink; width: 5%; display: flex; justify-content: center; align-items: center;">
      <span style="font-size: 18pt" class="fa fa-user">&nbsp;</span>
    </div>
    <div class="column" style="background-color: red; justify-content: center; align-items: center; padding-top: 1em;">
      <div>&nbsp;</div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- User info/Settings row -->
  <div class="row" style="height: 30vh; border-bottom: 1px solid black; width: 100%;">
    <div class="column" style="background-color: purple; width: 5%; display: flex; justify-content: center; align-items: center;">
      <span style="font-size: 18pt" class="fa fa-cog">&nbsp;</span>
    </div>
    <div class="column" style="background-color: red; padding-top: 1em;">&nbsp;</div>
    <div class="column" style="background-color: red; padding-top: 1em;">&nbsp;</div>
  </div>

  <!-- Messages/Chat row -->
  <div class="row" style="height: 25vh; width: 100%;">
    <div class="column" style="background-color: salmon; width: 5%; display: flex; justify-content: center; align-items: center;">
      <span style="font-size: 18pt" class="fa fa-comment">&nbsp;</span>
    </div>
    <div class="column" style="background-color: red; padding-top: 1em;">
      <div>&nbsp;</div>
      <div>&nbsp;</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- End Main Body Area -->
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: use flex-basis to set the width, also be careful when using shorthand flex

Comment: This is why extracting thw inline styles to classes is the way to go. You're code just makes it harder to diagnose as it stands.

Comment: @Pete Hi Pete, ive updated the question to be specific about the divs im trying to edit. Do i use flex-basis on the parent div of the one im trying to edit. i tried giving the current one that has 5% a flex basis and it began from the end of the div if that makes sense? Also what is shorthand flex?

Comment: avoid inline css / js at all costs. Not only does it make for harder-to-read code but inline css has higher specificity, meaning unless your stylesheet rules have `!important` - they won't get overriden

Comment: If you want a specific width, don't set a `flex` value on the div...those will override any set width. Just use `width`. `flex:1` means "grow as much as possible within the available space.` `flex:` 0 0 5%` would work though...probably.

Comment: I think you need to read up more about flex to understand it more: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex

Comment: @Pete thanks for the link i'll check it out, i've just been going by bits an pieces ive seen on here.

Comment: [here's another good link](http://codepen.io/enxaneta/pen/adLPwv) shows you how the properties react

Comment: @Paulie_D who knew all you need is flex: 0.05! So how come i don't need to declare display: flex before doing this? (i will read up about it but just thought i would quickly ask)

Comment: @Pete Also bookmarked, thanks again! So in your opinion is Flex a good thing to learn? Because isn't it quite new on the scene (ish)? So would be a good long term thing to learn properly?

Comment: The spaces are important. `flex:0 0 5%` is shorthand and means "don't grow", "dont' shrink" and "start at 5% wide".

Comment: I think it's the best thing to use at the moment but will be replaced by grid as soon as that becomes standard

Comment: @Paulie_D Oh brilliant thanks! Someone did mention to be careful when using shorthand though!

Comment: @Pete So would you recommend learning grid instead? Not sure i've really heard of that, is it new? My only worry is i learn Flex, and then Grid because it's the new norm and start mixing them in confusion

Comment: I haven't started yet - just have a look at questions on here every now and then to see what it's about, I think it's going to be good in the future but I don't learn them until they are standardised as browsers may still change their implementations up until it is (like flex kept changing up until it became part of css3).  It also depends on what browsers you have to support - eg ie11 has limited  support for grids

Comment: @Pete Well i'll take the time to learn Flex then, it seems good and if it still get the same end result as Grid once you have the hang of it then im all for that. Really appreciate your time and help.

Answer (score 1):

In flexbox, instead of setting width you can try different approach.

width of the columns are divided itself, to override the width of a column you can use the flex style like `flex: 0 0 5%;`

it can be described as

```
flex: <flex-grow> <flex-shrink> <flex-basis>;
```

This is the shorthand for flex-grow, flex-shrink and flex-basis combined

`flex: none | [ <'flex-grow'> <'flex-shrink'>? || <'flex-basis'> ]`

Answer (score 0):

Please check the below working example, based on your code, set the width of the columns as `flex: 0 0 5%;` instead of `width: 5%`.

```css
@media screen and (min-width: 800px) {
  .row {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
    width: 100%;
  }
  .column {
    -ms-flex-preferred-size: 0;
    flex-basis: 0;
    -ms-flex-positive: 1;
    flex-grow: 1;
    max-width: 100%;
  }
  .h-30vh {
    height: 30vh;
  }
  .w-5per {
    -ms-flex: 0 0 5%;
    flex: 0 0 5%;
    max-width: 5%;
    justify-content: center;
    align-content: center;
  }
  .bg-pink {
    background-color: pink;
  }
  .bg-purple {
    background-color: purple;
  }
  .bg-red {
    background-color: red;
  }
  .bg-salmon {
    background-color: salmon;
  }
  .column span {
    font-size: 18pt;
    display: flex;
  }
  .d-flex {
    display: flex;
  }
  .pt-1em {
    padding-top: 1em;
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="row h-30vh">
  <div class="column bg-pink w-5per">
    <span class="fa fa-user">&nbsp;</span>
  </div>
  <div class="column bg-red">
    <div>&nbsp;</div>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- User info/Settings row -->
<div class="row h-30vh">
  <div class="column bg-purple w-5per">
    <span class="fa fa-cog">&nbsp;</span>
  </div>
  <div class="column bg-red d-flex">&nbsp;</div>
  <div class="column bg-red d-flex">&nbsp;</div>
</div>

<!-- Messages/Chat row -->
<div class="row h-25vh bg-salmon">
  <div class="column w-5per">
    <span class="fa fa-comment">&nbsp;</span>
  </div>
  <div class="column bg-red pt-1em">
    <div>&nbsp;</div>
    <div>&nbsp;</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

just try to give max-width or min-width in place of width